# Avoiding password pop ups in JSch

Tags: java, jsch

I want to bypass the password step/password pop-up. I was actually trying to assign the password internally upon pop-up. I don't want user to type it again and again.

Right now I can pass it internally by clicking on OK without anything in the textfield of password , but I want to get rid of the prompt

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.*;

public class JumpHosts {

    TextPanel textPanel = new TextPanel();
    public static String my_password = "password";

public void JumpHosts(final String[] arg,final String command,final TextPanel textPanel) {

    StringBuffer resultDisplayBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker(){

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                try{
                      JSch jsch = new JSch();

                      if(arg.length <= 1){
                        System.out.println("This program expects more arguments.");
                        System.exit(-1);
                      }

                      Session session = null;
                      Session[] sessions = new Session[arg.length];

                      String host = arg[0];
                      String user = host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
                      host = host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

                      sessions[0] = session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
                      session.setUserInfo(new MyUserInfo());
                      session.connect();
                      //resultDisplayBuffer.append("The session has been established to "+user+"@"+host+"\n");
                      textPanel.appendText("The session has been established to "+user+"@"+host+"\n",textPanel);

                      for(int i = 1; i < arg.length; i++){
                        host = arg[i];
                        user = host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
                        host = host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

                        int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(0, host, 22);
                        //resultDisplayBuffer.append("portforwarding: "+
                        //        "localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+host+":"+22+"\n");
                        textPanel.appendText("portforwarding: "+
                                        "localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+host+":"+22+"\n",textPanel);
                        sessions[i] = session =
                          jsch.getSession(user, "localhost", assinged_port);

                        session.setUserInfo(new MyUserInfo());
                        session.setHostKeyAlias(host);
                        session.connect();
                        //resultDisplayBuffer.append("The session has been established to "+
                        //        user+"@"+host+"\n");
                        textPanel.appendText("The session has been established to "+
                                        user+"@"+host+"\n",textPanel);
                      }

                      //String command=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter command, execed with sudo", 
                      //        "printenv SUDO_USER");

//                      String sudo_pass=null;
//                      {
//                      JTextField passwordField=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(8);
//                      Object[] ob={passwordField}; 
//                      int result=
//                      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
//                           ob,
//                           "Enter password for sudo",
//                           JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
//                      if(result!=JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
//                      System.exit(-1);
//                      }  
//                      sudo_pass=passwordField.getText();
//                      }

                        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");

                        // man sudo
                        //   -S  The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the
                        //       standard input instead of the terminal device.
                        //   -p  The -p (prompt) option allows you to override the default
                        //       password prompt and use a custom one.
                        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' "+command);

                        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
                        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
                        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

                        channel.connect();
                        out.write((my_password + "\n").getBytes());
                        out.flush();


                        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
                        while (true) {
                            while (in.available() > 0) {
                                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                                if (i < 0)
                                    break;
                                //resultDisplayBuffer.append(new String(tmp,0,i));
                                textPanel.appendText(new String(tmp,0,i),textPanel);    
                            }
                            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                                //resultDisplayBuffer.append(new String("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus())+ "\n");
                                textPanel.appendText(new String("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus())+ "\n",textPanel);       
                                break;
                            }
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (Exception ee) {
                                System.out.println(ee);
                            }
                        }
                        channel.disconnect();
                        //resultDisplayBuffer.append("Disconnect\n\n");
                        textPanel.appendText("Disconnect\n\n",textPanel);


                     for(int i = sessions.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                        sessions[i].disconnect();
                      }
                    }


                    catch(Exception e){
                      System.out.println(e);
                    }
                return null;
            }
          //return !("".equals(resultDisplayBuffer.toString())) ? resultDisplayBuffer.toString() : "Something is wrong here, check code for errors!";

            public void done(){
                try {
                    System.out.println(get());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    };
     sw.execute();
}


  public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return passwd; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
      Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
      int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
             str,
             "Warning", 
             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
             JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
             null, options, options[0]);
       return foo==0;
    }

    String passwd;
    //JTextField passwordField=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(20);

    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){
      //Object[] ob={passwordField}; 
      //int result=
      //JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
    //              JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
     // if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    passwd= my_password;//passwordField.getText();
    return true;
      //}
      //else{ return false; }
    }
    public void showMessage(String message){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
    final GridBagConstraints gbc = 
      new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,
                             GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                             GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                             new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
    private Container panel;
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo){
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
      gbc.gridy++;

      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

      JTextField[] texts=new JTextField[prompt.length];
      for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        if(echo[i]){
          texts[i]=new JTextField(20);
        }
        else{
          texts[i]=new JPasswordField(20);
        }
        panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
      }

      if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, 
                                       destination+": "+name,
                                       JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
         ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
      {
        String[] response = new String[] {my_password};//=new String[prompt.length];
//        for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
//          response[i]=texts[i].getText();
          return response;
        }
    //String[] response = null;
    //return response;
      //}
      //else{
        //return null;  // cancel
      //}
    return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have code of your own, you should include that in your question rather than just pointing everyone to a third-party example.

Comment: I tried commenting promptpassword but getting some error about turning myuserinfo method to abstract. I am new to java and don't have much idea about it

Comment: @Kenster any idea on this